# Modifying callback parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a service in angular to track events, and I want the controllers to be as dumb as possible about the event tracking.  For this service each controller will need to supply its own copy of the event function.  My current solution is below.

```
//tracking module
let tracked_events = ['Event1','Event2']
    .map(function(e){
    return {
      eventName:e,
      eventProperties: {}
    }
  });

let finishingTracking = (event) => {
    console.log("prentend this does something fancy...",event);
} 

let track = (eventName,fn) => {
var event = tracked_events.filter(e => e.eventName===eventName)[0];
  fn(event.eventProperties);
  //some other internal tracking function
  finishTracking(event);
}
//end tracking module

//called from a controller
track("Event 1",(event) => {
  event["User ID"] = 123;
  event["Company ID"] = 12

});
//some other controller
track("Event 2",(event) => {
    event["Manager ID"] = 345;
    event["Time Sent"] = Date.now()
}
```

This works well because each controller will only have to provide its own way to modify the event object and it won't know anything else about the tracking module.  From a design perspective, is this ok?  I'm not sure about modifying the callback parameters (V8 optimizations/side effects), but I can't think of another way that doesn't cause more changes to each controller that needs to do its own event tracking.  Any suggestions on this?

EDIT (prior to refactor)

```
   var eventProperties = { table: "Machines, has_rows: /*rows...*/ }
    some_service.list(data)
      .then(function (response) {
         tracking_service.track({
           eventName: 'Event 1',
           eventProperties: eventProperties
  });
```

AFTER

```
some_service.trackEvent(some_service.events.EVENT1, function (event) {
   event["Table"] = "Machines";
   event["Has Rows"] = response.data.machines.length > 0;
});
```

An object of shape `{eventName: "Name", eventProperties:{} }` is currently being defined in each controller.  My solution was to pass in the eventName from a constant defined in the service and the callback function modifies the eventProperties of the object.  Each controller will have a different set of properties in eventProperties.

After the callback in version two runs, the service does the actual "tracking".  My aim was to have a function that prepared the eventProperties object and added whatever properties it needed before being actually tracked.

```
self.trackEvent = function (eventName, fn) {
      //var event = TRACKED_EVENTS.filter(e => e.eventName === eventName)[0];
      var event = {
        eventName: self.events[eventName],
        eventProperties: { }
      }
      fn(event.eventProperties); //this is the callback that does the prep
      self.track(event); //does the actually tracking
    }
```

Comment: Your code is fine, in my opinion. Other option is to use $rootScope.$broadcast in your Controllers, and $rootScope.$on in your Services.

Comment: It isn't clear what the *events* are and how this works together. If this is pub-sub thing then scope events are already there, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: the events are application specific events (e.g. "itemCreated", not DOM events), and the event parameter in the callback will contain state from services and state from the controller's scope.  the event is being passed to a third party analytics platform.

Comment: Event buses are beneficial for some loosely coupled tasks (particularly good for DOM), but most times they are coupled too loosely. It isn't clear why events are used in the first place. The obvious choice for data layer is a model (as in MVC) service. You're right about worrying about design perspective here, it doesn't look very good, but there are not enough details to suggest anything specific.

Comment: Events is a poor choice of words.  I'm not actually emitting or subscribing to events.  I'll edit the question with some mock code to give more context.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still positive about model. There's no reason why data should be packed into clumsy callbacks, something like `trackingModelService.addEvent('event name', { ... })` is more straightforward and conventional. It looks like callbacks are called synchronously, and something like `Date.now()` is evaluated instantly (if it isn't, there should be 'magic' constants to designate special values).

Comment: There isn't anything async going on.  I just wanted a way to keep clutter out of the controllers.  We currently have objects defined in the controllers for these "events" that feel like to me they have no place being there, certainly not in controller-level scope where anything could mess with them.  That was the idea behind using the callbacks, to prevent data from being changed and not having to define it except in the service that uses it.

Comment: Then look no further than `trackingModelService.addEvent('event name', { ... })`. The only good reasons to pack data assignment into a callback are async or multiple calls.